# Notify when bluetooth is on

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, observer-pattern, android-bluetooth

I would like to perform some actions when the bluetooth get enabled. To start it I call `bluetoothAdapter.enable();`

on

`bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();`,

but the `bluetooth` do not get enabled instantly - it takes about `2-3 seconds`. Is there any general pattern to do this or should I implement `Observer` on it with some way?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

1) Register a RECEIVER in your Manifest on `BLUETOOTH STATE CHANGE` ACTION.

**Action**:- `<action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />`

2) On state change your receiver gets called, you can check the current STATE ON/OFF and do your task.

**Permission** :- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`

if you want to need this in local Activity it self, you can register receiver in your activity it self, it will look like below.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                                 BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (state) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                setButtonText("Bluetooth off");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                setButtonText("Turning Bluetooth off...");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                setButtonText("Bluetooth on");
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                setButtonText("Turning Bluetooth on...");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

if want to listen the state change throughout till your app installed in the phone. Register it in manifest like I said above.

Answer (score 0):

Write a reciver for bluetooth state change

```
   class MyReciver extents  BroadCastReceiver{
        @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
                 String event = intent.getAction();    
               if(event.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED") {
                      //Do your code.
                      }
               }
}
```

put the uses permission and declare reciver in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<receiver android:name=".BTReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />           
        </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```